# Django call_command before loading fixtures in tests

Tags: django

Is it possible to `call_command()` before loading the fixtures in `TestCase`?

This code doesn't work - fixtures can't be loaded because the groups do not exist yet.

```
class UserAPITestCase(APITestCase):
    fixtures = [
        'user/fixtures/user.json',
    ]

    def _fixture_setup(self):
        call_command('create_groups')
        super()._fixture_setup()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like fixtures are loaded in setUpClass of TestCase so you could override that in our test class.

```
def setUpClass(cls):
    call_command('create_groups')
    super().setUpClass()
```

After looking further at that method, this may not play well with transactions, as you'd be loading database data before things are wrapped in a transaction. If you're not changing those groups though, I *think* everything would be fine. Apologies I didn't set up my own test case to confirm.

If that's an issue, your other option to dump the groups created by that command to a fixture :)